# Webservice over SSL endpoint not found with 404

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, security

I've got a webservice up and running and through the browser I can reach it and see it's up and running. Also without https I can make calls to the webservice.

To make calls at the moment I'm using a small console application to test and see the results.

Server side my web.config is as following:

The service section

```
<services>
    <service name="Website.mynamespace.Service1">
        <endpoint address="/service.svc" behaviorConfiguration=""  binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SomeDLLFile.Anothernamespace.Services.Proxy.Interface1" ></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="/service.svc" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SomeDLLFile.Anothernamespace.Services.Proxy.Interface1" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
      <service name="Website.mynamespace.Service2">
        <endpoint address="/service.svc" behaviorConfiguration=""  binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SomeDLLFile.Anothernamespace.Services.Proxy.Interface2" ></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="/service.svc" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SomeDLLFile.Anothernamespace.Services.Proxy.Interface2" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
</services>
```

The used binding

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

On the client side (my console application) i've added an service reference to my webservice. This way I'm able to make calls over HTTP. However when using HTTPS i'm getting an error saying the following

*`"There was no endpoint listening at https://test.mywebsite.nl/service.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."`*

The app.config from my console application looks like this;

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="https://test.mywebsite.nl/service.svc" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProxyInterface1"
                contract="Service.IProxyInterface1" 
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IProxyClientInterface" />
      <endpoint address="https://test.mywebsite.nl/service.svc" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProxyInterface2"
                contract="Service.IProxyInterface2" 
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IProxyInterface2" />
</client>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <!-- 
      Step 2. Inside a <serviceBehaviors> section, add 
      a name attribute in the <behaviors> element that 
      matches the behaviorConfiguration attribute in the
      <service> element above.
    -->
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

When i'm looking at the inner exception I'm looking at an 404-error. I've tried various suggestion from other topics on SO and also articles at MS, but I must be missing something since i'm still represented with the same error. Anybody any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue solved thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876955/wcf-service-returns-404-over-https-but-not-http) topic here on SO.

The problem was in the service name, so I combined the endpoints to both contracts in one service definition. I also changed the wsHttpBinding to an basicHttpBinding.

Comment: Could you please post your new definition as an answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar and installed a Self Certified SSL certificate in IIS. Try:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx

Obviously you will need to buy a proper certificate when you come to deploy into your production environment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, the environment i'm connecting to has a proper ssl-certificate. The url's posted in the question are faked because I'm not allowed to display the actual project this issue is about.